# Sending dynamic values in soap messages in JMeter

Tags: java, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

Can someone let me know how to send dynamic values in soap messages during the load test in JMeter?
I tried BeanShell Preprocessor and used the code given below :

import java.util.Random;

randomstring ="";

> int number = 0; for (int i=0; i <= 1; i++) {   randomstring =
> number.toString();    print(randomstring);
> vars.put("randomstring",randomstring);   number++; }

**It's sending the same value again and again.I want to send different value every time.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you're overwriting the `randomstring` variable on each iteration so only last occurrence is getting stored.

Also, [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for scripting where possible.

And finally, you don't even need to go for scripting, if all you need is to generate a random number - it is easily achievable via JMeter's built-in [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) which can be placed directly in the SOAP message body:

```
${__Random(1,2147483647,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)